# How to send and read binary data in TinyXML?

Tags: tinyxml

I need to send file data (picture,text, word,excel etc) in xml. I need to send file data as binary data. I read some article about this but couldnt get how to achieve in TinyXml. Please read below post:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/send-binary-data-in-xml/1050529

Above post has mentioned three approaches. Now let me know what approach is possible in tinyXML. If possible send me some sample code to send and read binary data in tinyXML. I searched a lot but couldnt get any way of doing this.

If sample code is not possible then please list down API I need to use so I will try that and update here my status.